# How to get rid of name of column/axis name showing on top of /above index in dataframe pandas python: Renaming axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Current dataframe**

[image]

---

### Expected output

---

[image]

when I do df.columns() this is what I get:

```
[IN] df.columns
[OUT] Index(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'],
      dtype='object', name='SKU')
```

When I do df.columns SKU is shown as name of columns as shown above.

Dtypes are as below

```
 [IN] df.dtypes
 [OUT]

SKU
Col1          float64
Col2          float64
Col3          float64
Col4          float64
dtype: object
```

Date is the index.

```
  [IN]  df.index.name
  [OUT] 'Date'
```

**What I want**

I **want to remove SKU** from my dataframe. It is **extra on top of date/index in the dataframe** as shown in the image.

Comment: Now the title Date is gone. I am getting SKU instead of date'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove columns name `SKU` by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

But I think empty row is not removed, need also remove index name `date`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

Both together:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

Comment: Following this, I am getting column name as nothing, neither date nor SKU

Comment: Over date column there is no title now. Other titles col1, col2 etc are intact, but the index column has no title now

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - `I want to remove SKU from my dataframe.` Do you need to remove `SKU` ? Or something else? I not understand.

Comment: `Yes I want to remove SKU`, but I want to retain the name `Date`

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - OK, then use only `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: pls check expected output image. I edited my question

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - So `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)` not working?

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - Or you need `df = df.rename_axis(df.index.name, axis=1)`, but it only move index name to column name

Comment: Sorry, I had used so many commands as mentioned here, I had to reset to original to check. Your solution worked. `df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it 1st by removing from *csv* file but if you want to do via using code just write it down

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 4, 7, 10],
                   'year': [2012, 2014, 2013, 2014],
                   'sale': [55, 40, 84, 31]})
df
   month  year  sale
0      1  2012    55
1      4  2014    40
2      7  2013    84
3     10  2014    31
```

to

```
df.set_index('month')
       year  sale
month
1      2012    55
4      2014    40
7      2013    84
10     2014    31
```

Visit https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: I cant change axis name. I am working on code after someone else has worked on it. That person has left organisation, I need to work on the dataframe as it is given. Pls tell me how I can proceed with the given dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You have to swap the columns and index names and then remove index name:

```
df.columns.name = df.index.name
df.index.name = None
```